# Thumbor upload with crop parameters

Tags: thumbor

I'm new to thumbor, but i was wondering if it is possible to apply filters / resizing / cropping parameters on upload ?

I have searched in the documentation, but have not found anything.

Cropping is possible with the original image, but i want to upload an image with crop parameters and store the cropped image as the original.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the code you can do it
use [docs](https://square.github.io/pollexor/2.x/pollexor/com/squareup/pollexor/class-use/ThumborUrlBuilder.html) for the different methods
I would suggest to add a user interface if you want the user to decide the cropping sizes and then return the image after cropping it.